React Native CLI Push Notification (react-native-push-notification npm package)
I am trying to add push notification for my react native cli app and currently using use the react-native-push-notification package. I followed all the steps as per the given docs but in the AndroidManifest.xml when I add the mentioned changes as per the docs the app build fails. When I rollback the changes in AndroidManifest.xml file the app build is success. The other changes (mentioned in docs) are not throwing any error, only this AndroidManifest.xml file gives me err.
Here is the screenshot of the err

This is the lines I added as per the docs react-native-push-notification

What changes needs to be updated to fix the error or is there any other new npm packages available to implement the push notifications in RN CLI app ?

you may need to add the android:exported=true to you manifest since you'll run in android 12 devices https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/issues/2419

I strongly recommend you to use @notifee/react-native. The library is well maintained and backed up by great contributors.
The library which you mentioned is not maintained and 3 years old since last update which is not recommended.
Also, using @notifee/react-native, you will get seamless integration with firebase with their https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage docs.
I have personally used @notifee/react-native in many projects and faced 0 issues

Thank you - actually I am new to this push notifications, will check this package. If u have any sample/example repo could u please share

@gopinathkrm sure
here is the link to a blog which i can suggest
https://medium.com/@sunilkumawat6268/integrate-push-notifications-in-react-native-using-notifee-a-complete-guide-cb2fd7cda179
also
I highly recommend to go through the docs of notifee/react-native, they have maintained the docs up to date and also very easy to understand
you can read the docs of notifee here
https://notifee.app/react-native/docs/overview
let me know if you face any issue
